# Check network connectivity before calling inappbrowser using Ionic 2 - hosted webapp

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I am a beginner studying Ionic 2 and trying to create an app shell to my webapp, I was able to make it work using inappbrowser directly in my index.html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://myWebApp.com', '_self', 'location=no, zoom=no, toolbar=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
}

</script>
```

The problem is that now I am trying to check if there's internet connection before I try to launch the web app but nothing happens with the code below, not even a error, just a blank screen after the splash screen...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://myWebApp.com', '_self', 'location=no, zoom=no, toolbar=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    });
  } else {
    alert('you are offline');
  }
}
</script>
```

For now I don't want to move my web app to run entirely native in the app, Im just learning and want to run it as a browser but making basic check of connectivity.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this? Is there any way to debug code which needs the device to run?
Remember I am a noob so explain your answer in more details if you can please.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lays here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/ They have created a plugin to check the details you are looking for. The link show you how to use the plugin.

And thier own quick example:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Comment: How can we differentiate between connected and online?

Comment: Add an event hook to the network change state. If connected then make a request to a website (with a timeout) if you get a response then online, if it times out then not.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this plugin:

[cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/)